# How to configure ganache to test in polygon instead of ethereum

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, polygon, ganache

I was able to set up ganache today to learn about blockchain and try out solidity, truffle, VSCode to start developing.

How should I configure the environment in order to learn polygon too?

I guess I need to create a new ganache but with what info?

I want to achieve an environent in my local to test around polygon too (I should see matic, not eth)

Answer (score 0):

Ganache will run a new network on its own. They are almost the same networks and the procedures of application development in Ethereum-like networks are as follows.

1. Write your contracts in **solidity** language.
2. **Deploy** and **Test** your contract in local **Ganache** (or any other) network and fix it until it's behaving exactly as what you expect.
3. **Deploy** your contracts to any available testnet to test its functionalities in a real environment and maybe more people could help.
4. It's time for any of the available mainnets. Deploy your application on Ethereum or Polygon or even BSC and Arbitrum and so on. These are the production environments.

Remember those networks have no major differences and each of them have their own testnet(s). For example Ethereum's testnet is GoErli. All that matters here is the price you pay for deploying your app. On local networks it's free on testnets almost free but in mainnets price is pretty high.